# Make default primary required field into a lookup

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

When creating a new entity, a new form is automatically created for you where it automatically is given 2 fields, name and owner.  For the name field, it is possible to make that into a lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the primary field can only be of the type *Single Line of Text*.

When creating a new entity, you cannot select other types:

[image: Primary Field Data Type]

This does not stop you from changing the requirement level of the primary field to *None* and creating your lookup field.

Comment: In that case, whats the recommended solutiion for the following?  I can make a lookup after the Name within the form, and hide the default name field.  Will that cause any issues in the long run?  If yes, whats the best work around?  I basically want the Name to be a lookup from the contacts.

Comment: Yes, it is OK to hide the primary field on the form. You should only take into consideration that the contents of the primary field is always shown at the top of the form, so it makes sense to have a plugin/workflow populate the primary field with meaningful data, e.g. based on your lookup field.

Comment: I see, so some form of client side JavaScript to copy the contact of the lookup into the primary name field would be fine?

Comment: JavaScript could work, though I would recommend doing it with a plugin/workflow to have it work for all records, no matter if they are created from the UI or not.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Will accept asap when stackoverflow allows me to in about 7 minutes time.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me asking an extra related question.  I've created a workflow which copies the info from the lookup to the primary field which works fine when the record is created.  Is that all I need to do, or do I need to make it a bit more robust as in, update the primary field if the lookup is changed etc?

Comment: That is up to you. You don't "need" to do anything, since this only affects the name shown at the top of the form. It should be a quick win to also trigger when another related record is chosen. Of course it would be nicest for the users if that name is also updated when e.g. the name of the related contact changes (but I must admit that I only have a generic plugin to set the name when the lookup itself changes, not when the name of the related lookup is changed).

Comment: @oshirowanen The name is used in a couple places,  the top of the form as henrik defines, as well as the value in lookups, and the join field when doing importing of data via the Data Migration Tool / Excel (without Guids)